# Android ActionBar Tabs and Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am getting started with android and want to have an application that has several tabs.  I want to use the actionbar with the SherlockActionBar library to support devices running pre honeycomb versions of android.  I have seen so many examples of creating and using tabs that I have no idea now what is the best or preferred method of doing so.

I have read that the best way is to have a fragment for each tab and have one activity which controls the switching of fragments in an out as well as coordinating communication between fragments. If this is the proper way of handling tabs is it best to have each fragments layout defined in its own layout.xml.

It seems that when an button is clicked that is defined in a fragments layout the onclick is triggered in the parent activity.  If the best way to handle that to do the processing in the parent activity or to pass the event on to the correct fragment for processing.

In summary I want to know what the best practice is for creating an app with actionbar tabs, where the code should be and how the layouts should be separated.

Thank You,
Nathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the right direction from what I can read. [Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) has a lot of the best material on this subject. Also look at Googles apps for reference, the Play app features simple tab navigation and defines how we should and should not try to make tabs. One very important lesson is that we should only have 1 fragment in each tab and we shouldn't try to make back navigation inside tabs (though it is possible by hacking a little).

Comment: Thanks,  I have read the google docs on it several times but it doesn't really go into detail about how to setup the fragments with layouts.

Comment: @Nath5 but layout is just the way it works with any regular fragments. you create you layout in the onCreateView() method inside the fragment.

Comment: @Warpzit can you tell us more about why having back navigation within tabs is wrong in android, and the proper way navigation should be handled when dealing with tabs (dialogs, opening new activities..)?

Comment: Yes I've answered more in detail on a similar post right here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13154701/969325. Basically it's not the way google does it and when you try to do stuff differently you'll be swimming against the stream. Also it's nice to give your users more screen room for important stuff.