# android FragmentTransaction.remove not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have a `Fragment` stack, which fragments are `add`ed to (not `replace`d). The problem is, because of memory issues, I don't want to have more than a specific amount of fragments in the stack. Suppose I have added fragments **A**, **B**, **C**, **D** to the stack. Now that I want to `add` the `Fragment` **E**, I want the `A` to be removed, using this piece of code:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragmentA).commit()
```

I get `fragmentA` using `findFragmentByTag()` and I am sure `fragmentA` exists and is in the stack. But this has no effect, and doesn't remove `fragmentA`.

What's wrong you think?
Is it possible to remove a fragment from bottom of the stack?

Comment: *What's wrong you think?* You assumption that it *has no effect, and doesn't remove* is wrong ... How did you check it?

Comment: I press back until I reach fragment A, and it exists. getBackStackCount also proves and also calling findFragmentByTag again with the same tag finds the fragment that should have been removed.

Comment: try calling executePendingTransactions http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions()

Comment: @diedu tried, but didn't work.

Comment: see this to get how you can write your stack : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854105/custom-back-stack-for-each-fragment-in-tabhost-in-android