# Keeping track of a fragment in the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, state, android-listfragment

in my app there's an Activity with a Navigation Drawer. The selection of the drawer's items brings to the instantiation of related List Fragments. 
When I select an item in the List Fragment, a second Activity begins showing information about the item I clicked. 
Navigating back to the first Activity, it gets created again, but I'd like to keep track of the last fragment showed, with the list from which I selected the item. 
How could I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: make use of **.addToBackStack()**

Comment: Cannot open New Activity to show information about the item you can open another fragment and add this fragment to backstack and then navigate back to it call the first frgament .

Comment: In your manifest did you try adding 
android:launchMode="singleTop"
to your first Activity?

Comment: Does selecting an item starts a fragment or an acitivity? because this statement is making question confusing. "When I select an item in the List Fragment, a second Activity begins showing information about the item I clicked."

Comment: @MohammedJunaid I tried with `android:launchMode="singleTop"` and seems working! Thank you!

Comment: @px91 great. posted it as answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Back Stack for each Fragment in TabHost in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854105/custom-back-stack-for-each-fragment-in-tabhost-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

to your first Activity in your manifest file.